# Is there an R function to subset multiple data that uses numbers and letters in one column?

Tags: r, object, dplyr, filter

I am trying to filter data ("E11719","E11710","E11718",...) from an object with a column consisting of data with numbers and letters. How can I filter this?

```
df <- choose.files()
df <- read.csv(df)
df35 <- dplyr::filter(df$Name_Abbr, "E11907","E12018","E12001","E12000")
```

> Error in UseMethod("filter") :
> no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character"

```
df
```

Example of the first row:

```
   Name                                                  Name_G  Name_Abbr 
1  BetaCoV.bat.China.Rhinolophus_blythi.PrC31.MW703458   Gen1    B1       bat

Country.Species Continents   Longitude   Latitude  Color
bat             Bat          #N/A        #N/A      red
```

Comment: `filter` requires a logical expression. Your expression is not logical.  Based on the code, maybe you want `filter(df, Name_Abbr %in% c("E11907","E12018","E12001","E12000"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of your `filter()` function is not correct. The first argument should be `.data`, which is a dataframe, but not a vector (`df$Name_Abbr` will return a vector).

I'm not sure which genes do you wish to include. If you wish to include all genes that starts with `E1`, you can do the following:

```
df %>% filter(grepl("^E1", Name_Abbr))
```

or

```
filter(df, grepl("^E1", Name_Abbr))
```

`grepl()` returns logical values, so `grepl("^E1", Name_Abbr)` will look for anything that starts (regex `^`) with `E1` in the `Name_Abbr` column.